# How to extract correct fields and count to create report in Splunk?

Tags: splunk

2012-06-21 23:59:33,902 [G4L11] DEBUG - AUDIT|2012-06-21|23:59:33|4|11|IPM961|PSA Corpo|45|6900|644133||N|N|||||||||||PCIU 4537852|PCIU 4537852||5|||||||||**YES**|A|CL$TCS|Y|682|

I have to create a pie chart to show the count values of YES and NO.
Firstly I tried to extract fields for autocontirm YES by IFX option, 
but the result I got is not correct.
Example: there are a total of 2320 lines (YES for 2054 and NO for 266)
but after extraction, YES count is 2054 (which is correct) but NO count is only 21. 
How to extract correctly? 
Please help me, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following regex:

```
([^\|]+)\|[^\|]+\|[^\|]+\|[^\|]+\|[^\|]+\|$
```